# Map equivalent of nested list comprehension using zip

Tags: python, list

Below, I have a list of ids and a list of number of urls to create for each id, using the `url_str` as the base of the created urls. So, for id `id2`, I'd expect three urls. I've accomplished this with a `list comprehension`, which seems to be the most pythonic way to solve the problem.

However, I'm learning python at the moment and I'm curious about the `map` equivalent to the list comprehension.

```
url_str = "www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/"
ids = ['id' + str(x) for x in xrange(1, 5)]
revs = [1, 3, 1, 8]

# ids output
['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']


# list comprehension
urls_compr = [url_str + id_r + "page=" + str(x)
              for id_r, page in zip(ids, revs)
              for x in xrange(1, page + 1)] 



# output of list comprehension
['www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id1page=1',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id2page=1',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id2page=2',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id2page=3',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id3page=1',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=1',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=2',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=3',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=4',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=5',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=6',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=7',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=8']
```

Ideally, I'd have something to the effect of:

```
urls_map = map(func, ids, revs)

urls_map
['www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id1page=1',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id2page=1',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id2page=2',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id2page=3',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id3page=1',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=1',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=2',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=3',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=4',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=5',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=6',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=7',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4page=8']
```

I'm just not sure about the `func` part.

Comment: The tags on this are confusing. Are you saying you have a working list comp, which you have posted, and you want to rewrite it using map to get the exact same output as you already have? (Why?)

Comment: I've udated the tags. I have a working list comp, but I want to rewrite using map. Why?: because I'm new to the language and I'm curious, no other reason.

Comment: map doesn't really make sense here, it only works well when the operation on each element is a callable, for instance using `map(str, seq)` would be equivelent to `[str(x) for x in seq]` in python 2 or `(str(x) for x in seq)` in python 3 (list comp vs generator comp)  but when the operation like `url_str + id_r + "page=" + str(x)` you would have to implement that as a function / lambda and... no it isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: if you absolutely want to know the similar use of map would be `map((lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + "page=" + str(x[2])), ((url_str, id_r, x) for id_r, page in zip(ids, revs) for x in xrange(1, page + 1)))` but my gosh it is ugly.

Comment: I was thinking you could also `map` using a function that performs the `xrange` part inside the function, but then you'd end up with a list of lists that you'd have to flatten to produce the above result. Struggling to see a way around that at the moment.

Comment: Side note -- shouldn't the URLs produced have a `?` between `idN` and `page=X`?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, that's the farthest I could get, "lists of lists". After reading the comments, I think it makes sense to close this question. It appears that the list comprehension really is the best solution in this case. And yes, you're correct about the URL, I made up the urls.

Comment: @RyanErwin Once you get to the list of lists stage you can `from itertools import chain; list(chain(*list_of_lists))` to flatten it. However, I don't think that's the way to go. Your list comp is on the right track, but could be "cleaned up" a little bit (made easier to read, IMO). Illustrated in short answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that `map` existed before list comprehension existed, if you want to map a function to every element of a sequence, for example:

```
map(func, seq)
```

would be equivalent to:

```
[func(x) for x in seq]
```

Although in python 3 `map` returns an iterator so it would be closer to `(func(x) for x in seq)` with round brackets to indicate a generator.

List comprehension comes with the added bonus of being able to use *expressions* as well as / instead of callables.

For instance if you want to add one (`+1`) to each element of a list you can do:

```
[x + 1 for x in seq]
```

to rewrite this using `map` you would need to create a callable that adds one to the argument:

```
map(lambda x:x+1, seq)
```

Even further, using multiple variables in list comprehension is fairly simple:

```
[x+y for x,y in itertools.product(range(5), range(7))]
```

But the callable for `map` needs to only take one argument so you would need to use tuples to pack the elements together:

```
map((lambda pair: pair[0] + pair[1]), itertools.product(range(5),range(7)))
```

Your case is even more prone to confusion since the sequence is only built with nested for loops so you will very likely end up using generator expression for the sequence anyway:

```
map((lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + "page=" + str(x[2])), ((url_str, id_r, x) for id_r, page in zip(ids, revs) for x in xrange(1, page + 1)))
```

This is clearly not what `map` was intended for, I recommend you stick with list comprehension since it is the right tool for your job.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `map` is going to work out in a great way here but after I gave up on it I was at least able to simplify your list comp into something a little more readable and efficient:

```
In [31]: ids = xrange(1, 5)

In [32]: pages = (1, 3, 1, 8)

In [33]: pages_per_id = zip(ids, pages)

In [34]: url_str
Out[34]: 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id%s?page=%s'

In [35]: [url_str % (id, page_no) for id, pages in pages_per_id for page_no in range(1, pages+1)]
Out[35]:
['www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id1?page=1',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id2?page=1',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id2?page=2',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id2?page=3',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id3?page=1',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4?page=1',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4?page=2',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4?page=3',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4?page=4',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4?page=5',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4?page=6',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4?page=7',
 'www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/id4?page=8']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to delete the question, because someone was able to answer my question in the comments above.

```
 map((lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + "page=" + str(x[2])), ((url_str, id_r, x) for id_r, page in zip(ids, revs) for x in xrange(1, page + 1)))
```

Comment: I put my answer into an answer with more explanation.